# How do I embed a Facebook live ( video ) URL on a my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-live-api

I'm wondering if it is possible to embed a facebook live  video stream, on a website, and how you go about doing it.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/

Answer (score 3):

You can embed Facebook live stream as simple

Just use your iframe src link like this:

```
src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/username/live"
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/32ntsf04/

Comment: this is very useful, thanks for your answer.

Comment: it works !! where did you find it ? can you please refer the documentation link ?

Comment: I found it myself by testing 

Answer (score 0):

FB does not give you an easy way to stream live on a website while you are live on FB but it is possible. You would just grab the embed code just like you would from any FB video. You would then need to update the Live video ID in the embed code every time you are live... not very convenient.

You get the Facebook Live Video ID from the URL of the page you are live on.

There are a few wordpress plugins that will help you do this, or you can look at https://vidlive.co. Create a widget, put it on any website and it will stream live when your are live on FB.