# Does Facebook have one embed code that works for all live streams?

Tags: facebook, live-streaming

I'm working on a project where I have a website that has a live streaming page for a Facebook Live stream.  I want to right now I can embed the live stream embed code on the page but I noticed that I would have to change that embed code every single time I live stream something.  Does Facebook have a live stream embed code that is static or the same for every live stream I do so I don't have to change the embed code on my website every time?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: You should just have to change the ID.  What embed code are you using now?

Comment: Maybe that will be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64256497