# Scrape Facebook Gaming for Live channels?

Tags: facebook

With Mixer closing, people will be moving to Facebook Gaming. With Mixer, I was able to scrape for information to see if specific channels are live. If they were live, my program would automatically embed those channels to the top of my website.

Does Facebook Gaming have a similar feature in their API? I would like to be able to add a list of channels (some of which, I don't own), and check to see if they are currently live streaming. Is this possible? How?

Comment: Facebooks API is documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs.

Comment: That literally does not help. The Facebook API as documented does not allow you to scrape for live streams to people's channels.

Comment: Maybe that will be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64256497